# How to import nltk corpus in HDFS when I use hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, streaming, nltk, corpus

```
 I got a little problem I want to use nltk corpus in hdfs,But failed.For example I want to load nltk.stopwords in my python code.
 I use this http://eigenjoy.com/2009/11/18/how-to-use-cascading-with-hadoop-streaming/
```

I do all that say,but I don't know how to transform it in my work. My nltk file name is nltk-2.0.1.rc1 my pyam file name is PyYAML.3.0.1 so my commad is:

```
zip -r nltkandyaml.zip nltk-2.0.1.rc1 PyYAML.3.0.1
```

then it said "mv ntlkandyaml.zip /path/to/where/your/mapper/will/be/nltkandyaml.mod"

My mapper.py save in /home/mapreduce/mapper.py  so my command is:

```
mv ntlkandyaml.zip /home/mapreduce/nltkandyaml.mod
```

is that right?

then i zip my corpus stopwords:

```
zip -r /nltk_data/corpora/stopwords-flat.zip *
```

In my code I use:

```
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltkandyaml.mod')
yaml = importer.load_module('PyYAML-3.09')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk-2.1.0.1rc1')
from nltk.corpus.reader import stopwords
from nltk.corpus.reader import StopWordsCorpusReader
nltk.data.path+=["."]
stopwords = StopWordsCorpusReader(nltk.data.find('lib/stopwords-flat.zip'))
```

finally  I use command:

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/../streaming/hadoop-0.21.0-streaming.jar -input  
/user/root/input/voa.txt -output /user/root/output -mapper /home/../mapper.py -reducer  
/home/../reducer.py -file /home/../nltkandyaml.mod -file /home/../stopwords-flat.zip
```

please tell me where I'm wrong

thank you all

Comment: Can you paste the error message you get when you run your hadoop streaming job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what your problem / error is, but if you want the contents of stopwords-flat.zip to be available in the current working directory at runtime use the `-archives` flag rather than `-files` (which could be your problem as you're using `-file`).

Hadoop will unpack the named archive file (zip), and the contents will be available as if they were in the local directory of your running mapper:

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/../streaming/hadoop-0.21.0-streaming.jar \
  -input  /user/root/input/voa.txt 
  -output /user/root/output \
  -mapper /home/../mapper.py \
  -reducer /home/../reducer.py \
  -files /home/../nltkandyaml.mod \
  -archives /home/../stopwords-flat.zip
```

Comment: Thank for your answer,I use your answer but still failed.It till coudn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
    zip -r [your-nltk-package-name/nltk] nltk.zip

    zip -r [your-yaml-package-name/lib/yaml] yaml.zip
```

then in your script, add:

```
    importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.zip')
    importer2=zipimport.zipimporter('yaml.zip')
    yaml = importer2.load_module('yaml')
    nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
```

in your command, add:

```
    -file [path-to-your-zip-file]
```