# Hadoop and NLTK: Fails with stopwords

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to run a Python program on Hadoop.  The program involves the NLTK library.  The program also utilizes the Hadoop Streaming API, as described [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/#run-the-mapreduce-job).

**mapper.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#print stopwords.words('english')

for line in sys.stdin:
        print line,
```

**reducer.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
```

**Console command:**

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \ -file /hadoop/mapper.py -mapper /hadoop/mapper.py -file /hadoop/reducer.py -reducer /hadoop/reducer.py -input /hadoop/input.txt -output /hadoop/output
```

This runs perfectly, with the output simply containing the lines of the input file.

However, when this line (from mapper.py):

**#print stopwords.words('english')**

is *uncommented*, then the program fails and says

> Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed
>   limit. FailedCount: 1.

I have checked and in a standalone python program,

> print stopwords.words('english')

works perfectly fine, and so I am absolutely stumped as to why it's causing my Hadoop program to fail.

I would greatly appreciate any help!  Thank you

Comment: You don't have ntlk corpus in your hadoop directory.
Try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716302/how-to-import-nltk-corpus-in-hdfs-when-i-use-hadoop-streaming

Comment: Try this also---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job

Comment: @user1525721 Thanks for the replies.  Will give it a try and post back.  If I have NLTK on all the nodes though, would this still be necessary?

Comment: you provide path to your mapper n reducer. Similarly you have to point out your python libraries in order to use it.

Comment: @user1525721  Thanks for the clarification.  Another question -- how come `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` doesn't cause it to fail?

Comment: @user1525721 Update: I have tried the same console command with the addition of `-file nltk_data.zip` and `-archives stopwords.zip`.  Unfortunately, having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is '*english*' a file in `print stopwords.words('english')`? If yes, you need to use `-file` for that too to send it across the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands to unzip :

```
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.zip')
    importer2=zipimport.zipimporter('yaml.zip')
    yaml = importer2.load_module('yaml')
    nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
```

CHeck the links which I pasted above. They have mentioned all the steps.

Comment: Do I need to send these files in the console command or have them stored locally on each machine?  Also, do I need nltk.zip or nltk_data.zip?  How can I find the former?  What role does yaml play in this?  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, and have imported nltk and yaml without any problems.  However, I still cannot get the stopwords working. `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` does not cause the program to fail, but as soon as I type `print stopwords.words('english')`, it fails.  Any idea how to fix?  I have included this in the console command: `-archives ./stopwords.zip`  Thanks!